# Log4j Logging for custom Log levels and Properties files in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have written class for custom logging level i.e. EVENT

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
public class SAMLLoggingLevel extends Level {

public static final int TRACE_INT = Level.DEBUG_INT - 1;
public static final int EVENT_INT = Level.INFO_INT + 2;
private static String TRACE_STR = "TRACE";
private static String EVENT_STR = "EVENT";

public static final SAMLLoggingLevel TRACE = new SAMLLoggingLevel(TRACE_INT, TRACE_STR, 7);
public static final SAMLLoggingLevel EVENT = new SAMLLoggingLevel(EVENT_INT, EVENT_STR, 0);

protected SAMLLoggingLevel(int level, String strLevel, int syslogEquiv) {
    super(level, strLevel, syslogEquiv);
}
public static Level toLevel(String sArg) {
    return (Level) toLevel(sArg, SAMLLoggingLevel.TRACE);
}
public static Level toLevel(String sArg, Level defaultValue) {
    if (sArg == null) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    String stringVal = sArg.toUpperCase();

    if (stringVal.equals(TRACE_STR)) {
        return SAMLLoggingLevel.TRACE;
    } else if (stringVal.equals(EVENT_STR)) {
        return SAMLLoggingLevel.EVENT;
    }
    return Level.toLevel(sArg, (Level) defaultValue);
}
public static Level toLevel(int i) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    switch (i) {
        case TRACE_INT:
            return SAMLLoggingLevel.TRACE;
        case EVENT_INT:
            return SAMLLoggingLevel.EVENT;
    }
    return Level.toLevel(i);
}}
```

my log4j.properteis file looks like this

```
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p [%t] %C %M - %m%n

log4j.appender.SAML_ROOT_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SAML_ROOT_APPENDER.Threshold=EVENT#com.test.saml.control.log.SAMLLoggingLevel
log4j.appender.SAML_ROOT_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SAML_ROOT_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p [%t] %c %C %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.SAML_ROOT_APPENDER.append=true   
log4j.appender.SAML_ROOT_APPENDER.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/samlLog/samlRoot.log

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,STDOUT
log4j.logger.saml.events=EVENT#com.test.saml.control.log.SAMLLoggingLevel, SAML_ROOT_APPENDER
```

Now what are changes I need to make in log4j.properties to print this custom Event logs in my log file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of Log4J are you using?

Comment: @hfontanez I am using log4j2.x version along with 3 jars log4j-api-2.17.0, log4j-core-2.17.0, and log4j-1.2-api-2.17.0.

Comment: I have used Log4J2 with custom logging levels and I don't remember this being this complicated. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish but I am sure there is a much simpler way to accomplish this.

Comment: It seems you are following [this example](https://crunchify.com/java-how-to-create-your-own-logging-level-in-log4j-configuring-log4j/). I have never done it this way. I used the recommended way in Log4J2 website. However, it seems all you need to do is add the custom logger class to your classes. There is a logger test in the link I provided. I suggest you try that first, then edit your post with specific information as to what is not working.

Comment: I have a requirement to print the logs in this hierarchy EVENT, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, where EVNET is the custom level logs.
I checked my prod server, earlier EVENT logs is printing look like below.

[2022-01-06 22:32:46,558] EVENT [Thread-68] com.test.saml.SAMLLoggingLevel.xyz.FormatNumbersFetch run - Format number fetch thread retrying to check switch value after sleeping for 300000 seconds

Comment: You are trying to use a Log4j 1.x custom level in Log4j 2.x.  `log4j-1.2-api` almost certainly does not support that: it is meant as a **basic** replacement for Log4j 1.x and does not support advanced features. See [Custom Log Levels](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html) on how to define new log levels in Log4j 2.x.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I knew something was funky because I personally migrated an application logging from 1.2.14 (I think) to Log4J2 about 4 years ago and I remember the struggle. But, once I read all the documentation on Log4J2 website, I was able to complete the migration without any issues. I said all that to reiterate my initial point: "_I have used Log4J2 with custom logging levels and I don't remember this being this complicated. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish but I am sure there is a much simpler way to accomplish this._"